# return function statement as formatted HTML Angular 9

Tags: angular, string, split

I am displaying a table using ngFor. For one particular column I have a string which needs to come as two line. I have split the string into two array values using a function. However, when I am returning the values as formatted html, in template, it is showing with html tags rather than formatted expression as required.

My .ts file code is

```
    isSplit(index, cdata){
    if(index == 6){
      return `${cdata.split(' ')[0]}<br/>${cdata.split(' ')[1]}' '${cdata.split(' ')[2]}`; 
    }
    else{
     return cdata
    }
  }
```

My .html file code is

```
<td *ngFor="let hero1 of hero.cell; let i=index"><span>{{isSplit(i,hero1._cdata)}}</span></td>
```

Output is coming as `$15,50<br/>Employee' 'Paid`

Desired output is

```
     $15,50
Employee Paid.
```

When I tried below way, it was coming as expected. I tried this within the template. However, due to *ngFor, I have changed my approach.

```
{{hero.cell[3]._cdata.split(' ')[0]}}<br/>{{hero.cell[3]._cdata.split(' ')[1]+' '}}{{hero.cell[3]._cdata.split(' ')[2]}}
```

So how can I achieve the expected result using *ngFor? Please note I can't split all strings due to some restriction.

Comment: So if get yor question right - you want to display data with html tags in it.. is that right? (in that case instead of {{yourdata}} you have to use something like this: <ng-container [innerHTML]=yourdata></ng-container>

Comment: Yes. I want exactly what you are saying. However, I have tried your solution. But it is showing error like "innerHTML is not a known property of ng-container.

Comment: Oh sorry try using a span tag instead of a ng-container.. oh and use [innerHTML]="yourdata"

Comment: I have tried with span tag. It is not working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a little demo (depending on your code) and it's working as expected:

My test data:

```
 hero = {
  cell: [
   {
    data: "Data Hello Test"
   },
   {
    data: "Data Hello XXX"
   }
  ]
 };
```

// Your function (changed nothing):

```
isSplit(index, cdata) {
    if (index == 1) {
      return `${cdata.split(" ")[0]}<br/>${cdata.split(" ")[1]}<br/>${cdata.split(" ")[2]}`;
    } else {
      return cdata;
    }
  }
```

// HTML Code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let hero1 of hero.cell; let i=index">
            <span [innerHTML]="isSplit(i, hero1.data)"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Output:

[image: Image of Output view]

I hope you can make it work now too :-)

Comment: Thank You. I have applied this logic and it has worked.